# Bootstrap - input in navbar spanning several columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

In Bootstrap 3.3.4, I try to have an input group in a navbar that spans 8 central columns, next to brand name. Unfortunately input group either seems to remain fixed size, or stretches input-group-addon. The code that is the closest to what I want to achieve (modulo this stretching) is this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsible">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <form class="navbar-form">
        <div class="form-group" style="width: 100%">
          <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  style="width: 100%">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the form a class of form it will allow the form group to stretch to 100% as you want.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsible">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <form class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group" style="">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbWMax

Comment: Thanks, but when I do it this way the input is not vertically centered.

Comment: oh that's simple. Just add some css to add the margin-top 8px and margin-bottom 8px to the form-group. Make sure it's specific to the navigation if you do it that way though. Pen should be updated to show what I mean.

Comment: OK, thanks - I thought there might be some ready to use classes that correct just that.